# Using Node.js to run multiple instances of external application with child_process

Tags: node.js, windows, cmd, child-process, iisnode

I am running node on windows server with iisnode. 
In my code I upload file and then start some external application to do conversion of this uploaded file. To do this I am using child_process.fork().
It works fine with one file. If I run two requests, so two instances of external application should be started, it doesn't work as intended. First request is fine, but second one fails, when trying to start second instance of external application.

I get message: "Error: Command failed: ..."

In Task Manager I can see that second instance of cmd and external application is started, but just for a second and then it terminates.

When I try to do this process manually, it works. I open two cmd windows and start two instances of this external application and they do file conversion without any problems.

What could be causing problems when trying to do this from node?

Comment: You can do it another way around using PM2 package.
Can this be option?

Comment: @HarshalYeole can you explain what would be approach using PM2?